# multiple form actions using selected radio button in php

Tags: jquery, radio-button

```
<p><h3 style="font-size:18px;">Call Status:</h3>


      <body>

    <div>

        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" <?php if (isset($colorRadio) && $colorRadio=="immediate" ) echo "checked";?>value="IMMEDIATE"> Call Immediate</label>

        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" <?php if (isset($colorRadio) && $colorRadio=="scheduled") echo "checked";?>value="SCHEDULED"> Call Scheduled</label>

        <label><input type="radio" name="colorRadio" <?php if (isset($colorRadio) && $colorRadio=="message") echo "checked";?>value="MESSAGE"> Leave Your Message</label>



    </div>

    <div class="IMMEDIATE box">You have selected <strong>red radio button</strong> so i am here</div>

    <div class="SCHEDULED box"> 
    <p>
    <td>
<input type="Text" id="demo1" name="demo1" maxlength="25" size="25"><a href="javascript:NewCal('demo1','DDMMYYYY',true,24)">
<img src="img/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0"></a>
<span class="descriptions">Pick a Date</span>
    </p>
    </div>

    <div class="MESSAGE box"> 
     <p>
        <label for="textarea" style="font-size:16px; font-weight:700; ">Your Message</label>
        <!--<input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="text" value="" />-->
        <br/><br/><textarea id="text" class="text" name="fmessage" style="FONT-SIZE:10pt" rows="5" cols="35" autocomplete="off"  required></textarea>
     </p>

    </div>


</body>
        </p>
```

I want to perform such multiple actions like whenever i select call Immediate radio button it will send in another page..as per same in call scheduled radio button case and also leave your message radio button... Please tell how to do this or please give some alternative for this...

Comment: Search for `ajax php`

Answer (score 0):

Quick fiddle ... this provides a means to recognise the click of the colorRadio ... then you can use an if statement to take the necessary action ...

```
$('input[name=colorRadio]').click(function(){
var status = $('input[name=colorRadio]:checked').val();
alert(status);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eamonnkillian/P9HWV/

Hope this helps 
EJK